# Alterar valor do json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tenho o seguinte JSON:

```
[{"id": 1,"preco": "R$50"}, {"id": 2,"preco": "R$70"}]
```

Gostaria de alterar o valor de 'preco' removendo o `R$` deixando somente os numeros usando javascript ou jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar o `.map()` para fazer isso, um exemplo seria:

```js
const arr = [{"id": 1, "preco": "R$50"}, {"id": 2, "preco": "R$70"}];
const formatado = arr.map(obj => {
  return {
    id: obj.id,
    preco: Number(obj.preco.slice(2))
  };
});

console.log(formatado);
```

A ideia é usar `.slice(2)` para remover os dois primeiros caracteres dessa string, e `Number` para converter em numero. Se quiseres podes usar string na mesma, ignorando o `Number`, depende do uso que irás dar a esses valores.